# Can the field of complex numbers be regarded as a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

This is from Huffman & Kunze.

"The field C of complex numbers may be regarded as a vector space over the field ℝ of real numbers. More generally, let F be the field of real numbers and let V be the set of n-tuples $\ α=(x_1,..,x_n)$ where $\ x_1,..,x_n$ are complex numbers. Define addition of vectors and scalar multiplication by:

a) let $\ α=(x_1,...,x_n)$ and $\ β=(y_1,...,y_n)$ then $\ α+β=(x_1+y_n,...,x_1+y_n)$

b) let $\ α=(x_1,...,x_n)$ then $\ cα=(cx_1,...,cx_n)$

In this way we obtain a vector space over the field ℝ which is quite different from $\ ℂ^n$ and $\ ℝ^n$"

1) How can the field of complex numbers be considered a vector space? I am asking because I don't think that the field of complex numbers can have n-tuples s.t. n>1, right? Since I believe that in order for an object to be interpreted as a vector, it must have at least an ordered pair of numbers.

2) When it was stated that the constructed vector space is quite different, shouldn't it be "entirely different" because the vector space has n-tuples s.t. n>1.

I am really confused.

Comment: This is no problem. We can indeed write $\mathbb{C}$ as $2$-tuples from $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$, with a special rule for multiplication.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between $\mathbb C$ and $\mathbb R^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/364044/difference-between-mathbb-c-and-mathbb-r2), or [How to prove that complex numbers (C) are linear space over real numbers (R) field?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48510/how-to-prove-that-complex-numbers-c-are-linear-space-over-real-numbers-r-fie)

Comment: "Since I believe that...at least an ordered pair of numbers." On base of what? Not on base of the definition, that's for sure. Your vision on vectorspaces is simply too small. $n$-tuples with $n>1$ might look common when it comes to vectorspaces, but are not really needed.

Comment: thank you for the clarifications and the link fellas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not necesarily the case that a vector space $V$ over a field $K$ consists of tuples.
It's an entirely abstract notion: we only need some addition with $0$ and $-$ (an Abelian group in abstract algebra) and a scalar multiplication which is just a function $K \times V \to V (k, v ) \to k\cdot v$ that satisfies some consistency axioms like

$(kk')\cdot v = k(k'\cdot )v$, tying multiplication in the field $K$ to scalar multiplication, as well as $1\cdot v = v$, $k\cdot(v+w) = k \cdot v + k\cdot w$ and $(k+k')\cdot v = k\cdot v + k'\cdot v$.

But if $K \subset V$ and $V$ is a field too, we can just use the field multiplication in $V$ restricted to $K$ on the left to get a scalar multiplication for free, and the field axioms garantuee all the vector space axioms. So $V$ is a vector space over $K$.

This is also sometimes used to see $\mathbb{R}$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$ (which has huge dimension), and in a finite field $K$ we always have a subfield of the form $F_p$ for $p$ prime, and the vector space argument then gives us that $|K| = p^n$ for some $n$ ($n$ is the dimension of $K$ as a vector space over $F_p$...)

It's just abstract algebra, not tuples/matrices etc. Later you'll probably see "vector spaces", consisting of functions or equivalence classes of functions, and linear maps that are not "matrices".

Comment: thank you for giving a more abstract definition. I understand it better now.

Answer (score 1):

It's because it fulfils the requirements of a vector space $V$ over $F$. They are:

- $V$ is an abelian group
- $\alpha(\beta u) = (\alpha\beta)u$
- $1 u = u$
- $\alpha (u+v) = \alpha u+\alpha v$
- $(\alpha+\beta)u = \alpha u + \beta u$

Where $u, v\in V$ and $\alpha, \beta\in F$ and $1$ being the multiplicative unity of $F$.

$\mathbb C$ fulfils all these requirements (with $\mathbb R$ being the field). The complex numbers kind of contains ordered pair, for example $z=x+iy$ contains the ordered pair $(x,y)$. The requirement to contain that doesn't mean that they must do that that explicitely (besides there's no such requirement - the definition allows for a vector space to be one or zero dimensional which means there would be no proper tuples at all in any way).

What is the distinction between quite different and entirely different? I don't know, but of course they are different. The constructed space has dimension $2n$ while $\mathbb C^n$ and $\mathbb R^n$ only has dimension $n$. The difference to $\mathbb R^{2n}$ on the other hand is not within the scope of the linear space part - regarded as linear space only they are isomorphic.

Comment: on what scope can we see the difference to $\ R^{2n}$ ?

Comment: @TheLastCipher What I mean is while $\mathbb C$ can be considered to be a linear space over $\mathbb R$ it has more structure than that that makes it stand out from $\mathbb R^2$. For example $\mathbb C$ is a field which $\mathbb R^2$ isn't. That is if you include operations that are outside the scope of linear spaces then the spaces differ (of course because the vectors are constructed differently).