# Find the dimension and a basis for each vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra

GIven that $\mathbb{C}$ is the complex field , $\mathbb{R}$  is the real field. Find the  dimension and a basis for each vector space.

- $\mathbb{C}$ over $\mathbb{R}$
- $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{C}$

My  attempts : I know that  $V$ is a vector space  over $F$ if the

$\lambda v \in V$   for  all $\lambda \in F$ and $v \in V$

Now  here, I take for option 1) basis  will be $\{1,i\}$ , dimension is $2$.i had confused 
 about option $2$

Is my answer is correct / not correct ?

Any hints/solution will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: soory  ,,i thinks  both have same basis, so their  dimension will be same @DietrichBurde

Comment: For b) see [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/154883/is-mathbbr-a-vector-space-over-mathbbc). Also a) is well-known, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48510/how-to-prove-that-complex-numbers-c-are-linear-space-over-real-numbers-r-fie).

Comment: @DietrichBurde.thanks  a lots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\mathbb{V}$ is a vector space  over $\mathbb{F}$ if the

$\lambda v \in \mathbb{V}$   for  all $\lambda \in \mathbb{F}$ and $v \in \mathbb{V}$

For option $2.)$ i $\in \mathbb{C}$ and   $1$   $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$  but   $ 1.i =i$ not belong $\mathbb{R}$